# Conversion from calendar format into timestamp format

Tags: timestamp, datetime

I see a lot of discussion about date and time, timestamp... But they don't answer to my question: How can i convert from calendar format into timestamp format for comparing datetime?

e.g: I have this smart contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract User {

    address userWalletAddr;
    string userName;
    string userEmail; //The start date of the production

    struct UserActivity{
        address userWalletAddr;
        string activityDescription;
        uint dateTime;
    }

    UserActivity[] private activities;

    constructor(string  memory _userName, string memory _userEmail) public {
        userWalletAddr = msg.sender;
        userName = _userName;
        userEmail = _userEmail;
    }

    function addUserActivity(string  memory _activityDescription) public {
            activities.push(UserActivity({
                    userWalletAddr : msg.sender,
                    activityDescription: _activityDescription,
                    dateTime: now
            }));
        }

    //Retrieve activities of a user according to an intervall of time
    function listUserActivities(address _userWalletAddr, uint _startInterVal, uint _endInterval)
        public view returns(address, string memory,  uint){
        for(uint i = 0; i <= activities.length; i ++){
            while(
                activities[i].userWalletAddr == _userWalletAddr &&
                activities[i].dateTime >= _startInterVal &&
                activities[i].dateTime < _endInterval)
                    {
                    return
                    (
                    activities[i].userWalletAddr,
                    activities[i].activityDescription,
                    activities[i].dateTime
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, i want to retrieve a list of activities of a user according an intervall [ _startInterVal, _endInterval] like indicated in the function listUserActivities().

Your help would please me

Comment: Can you define what "calendar format" and "timestamp format" mean to you? And what, if anything, do you not like about the current code you have?

Comment: Calendar format is appear like 08/21/2019 @ 12:00pm (UTC) that equivalent to 1566388800, the timestamp format(the number of seconds) since Jan 01 1970. (UTC).

Now, in my case, i want to retrieve a list of activities of a user according an intervall [ _startInterVal, _endInterval] that i will indicate in a User Interface.

e.g: The list of activities registered  from 08/15/2019 @ 12:00pm to  (UTC) 08/21/2019 @ 12:00pm (UTC).

Comment: Well, you would do this conversion in your UI (maybe JavaScript?), so start your search there. `moment.js` comes to mind as a good library for parsing dates.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simple.

Smart contract only saves UNIX timestamp.

You probably execute the Contract via JavaScript.

There you can create a Timestamp of current second with:

```
Date.now()
```

If you want to convert:

```
new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000
```

In case this doesn't work you need to cut the string using [substr()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

Then you can call it like this:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).getTime() / 1000
```